# Custom button class setuserinteractionenabled

Tags: objective-c, button, sprite-kit

Note: This is for an OS X app, not iOS app.

I am creating a custom button class, which is a subclass of SKSpriteNode. I wanted the class to be able handle button presses so I found out that I had to set setuserinteractionenabled to YES. When I do this for in my custom button class so that the mouseDown event receives messages my SKScene, which creates the button, no longer receives messages when the button is clicked. Is there a way that I can fix this? I even tried enabling setuserinteractionenabled in the SKScene, but to no avail. I can't find any questions on SO that address this.

Button.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

typedef enum ButtonState {
    UNPRESSED,
    PRESSED
} ButtonState;

@interface Button : SKSpriteNode

@property ButtonState state;

-(id)initButtonWithImage:(NSString*)unselectedImage selectedImage:(NSString*)selectedImage;
-(void)setButtonState:(NSString*)event;

@end
```

Button.m (custom button class)

```
#import "Button.h"

@interface Button()

@property SKSpriteNode *image;
@property SKSpriteNode *unselectedImage;
@property SKSpriteNode *selectedImage;

@end

@implementation Button

@synthesize state = _state;
@synthesize image = _image;
@synthesize unselectedImage = _unselectedImage;
@synthesize selectedImage = _selectedImage;

-(id)initButtonWithImage:(NSString*)unselectedImage selectedImage:(NSString*)selectedImage {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _unselectedImage = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:unselectedImage];
        _selectedImage = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:selectedImage];

        _image = _unselectedImage;
        _image.name = @"image";

        [self addChild:_image];
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setButtonState:(NSString*)event {
    [self removeAllChildren];
    if ([event isEqualToString:@"mousedown"])
        _image = _selectedImage;
    else if ([event isEqualToString:@"mouseup"])
        _image = _unselectedImage;

    [self addChild:_image];
}

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [self setButtonState:@"mousedown"];
}

-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [self setButtonState:@"mouseup"];
}

@end
```

GameMenu.m (an SKScene)

```
#import "GameMenu.h"
#import "NoteBlasterMenu.h"
#import "ChordAttackMenu.h"
#import "Button.h"

@implementation GameMenu

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES; //allows scene to register clicks

        [self initBackground];
        [self initButtons];
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) initBackground {
    SKSpriteNode *bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"menubg"];
    bg.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
    [self addChild:bg];
}

-(void) initButtons {
    Button *chordAttackButton = [[Button alloc] initButtonWithImage:@"chordattackbutton"
                                                      selectedImage:@"chordattackbuttonpressed"];
    chordAttackButton.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
    chordAttackButton.name = @"chordAttackButton";
    [self addChild:chordAttackButton];

    Button *noteBlasterButton = [[Button alloc] initButtonWithImage:@"noteblasterbutton"
                                                      selectedImage:@"noteblasterbuttonpressed"];
    noteBlasterButton.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2 - 150);
    noteBlasterButton.name = @"noteBlasterButton";
    [self addChild:noteBlasterButton];
}

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    CGPoint location = [theEvent locationInNode:self];
    NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:location];

    NSLog(@"I'm being pressed");

    for (SKNode *node in nodes) {
        if ([node isKindOfClass:[Button class]]) {
            Button *button = (Button*)node;

            if ([button.name isEqualToString:@"chordAttackButton"]) {
                SKScene *scene = [ChordAttackMenu sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(1280, 720)];
                [self.view presentScene:scene transition:[SKTransition fadeWithDuration:0.55]];
            }
            else if ([button.name isEqualToString:@"noteBlasterButton"]) {
                SKScene *scene = [NoteBlasterMenu sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(1280, 720)];
                [self.view presentScene:scene transition:[SKTransition fadeWithDuration:0.55]];
            }
        }
    }
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
....(header files etc)
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    /* Set up the window for the app */
    NSRect frame = [_window frame];
    frame.size = CGSizeMake(1280, 740);
    [_window setFrame: frame display: YES animate: NO];
    [_window center]; //sets the window to the centre of the screen

    /* Pick a size for the scene */
    //SKScene *scene = [ChordAttackMenu sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(1280, 720)]; //ChordAttack Menu
    //SKScene *scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(1280, 720)]; //ChordAttack
    //SKScene *scene = [NoteBlasterMenu sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(1280, 720)]; //BassBlaster Menu
    //SKScene *scene = [NoteBlaster sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(1280, 720)]; //BassBlaster
    SKScene *scene = [GameMenu sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(1280, 720)];

    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
    //scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    [self.skView presentScene:scene];

    self.skView.showsFPS = YES;
    self.skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
}

- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)sender {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your initButtons method in GameMenu.m, set the next responder for each button by

```
chordAttackButton.nextResponder = self;
noteBlasterButton.nextResponder = self;
```

In your Button class, pass the mouse down/up events up the responder chain by

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [self setButtonState:@"mousedown"];
    [super mouseDown:theEvent];
}

-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [self setButtonState:@"mouseup"];
    [super mouseUp:theEvent];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is weird. I am not the best with Objective c, as you can tell. But according to apples [Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventHandlingBasics/EventHandlingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH5-SW2) after you process the event you pass it up the responder chain with

```
[super theEvent];
```

But in this case, the GameScene is the buttons parent and not its superview. So, what you would need to do is call the event either like this:

```
[self.parent theEvent];
```

or

```
[self setNextResponder:referenceToGameScene];
[self.nextResponder theEvent];
```

It may be best to have a Controller that manages these events in a less convoluted way. Because every child added that you want to pass the events up the responder chain will need to have the code above implemented.

Comment: How do you do this? I tried this, but it gives me an error.

`chordAttackButton.acceptsFirstResponder = true;`

Comment: Oh sorry I'm dumb. You have to override it in your button class.

Comment: So I have to create a setter for the first responder? I'm a little confused. I've never worked with the first responder in any capacity before. Please help :/

Comment: Okay say I just created a project with your code and it seems like it works right. Can you post your AppDelegate.m?

Comment: Hey man/girl, I tested your code and messed around with it. It works fine for me. Both the button and the scene receive their proper events.

Comment: Wait do you want both the buttons and gamescenes mouseDown event to go off simultaneously?

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm looking to do so that I can handle what I need to do in the scene, but also so that the scene doesn't have to handle the image switching when the button is pressed. I want the button class to handle that.

Comment: Hopefully this edit will help. Sorry about the confusion and wasting your time @02fentym :(